# Android resource that scales on one axis and tiles on another

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

We're working on the Android version of one of our games and we're having a problem with a background image.  On iOS, it's really easy to scale the image down to the appropriate width and configure it to stretch vertically.

However, on Android, we can't figure out a way to do this.  Basically, because of the myriad screen sizes and resolutions, we'd like to have our background image (which frames the play area) scale down to fit the width of the screen.  Then, the bottom and top portions of the image should have the right aspect ratio but the middle part should tile (or stretch even) to fill the rest of the area.

We tried this with a nine-patch file but nine-patches don't scale down.  We've tried it with LayerDrawables which works well except that it won't tile the middle as the size of the layout changes; it just stretches the entire image instead.

Is there any way to get a drawable to scale to fit horizontally and then tile a section to grow vertically?